# (Error connecting to Redis on localhost:6379 (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I deploy small rails app on heroku with one CRUD.

heroku config --app painting-art

```
This is the legacy Heroku CLI. Please install the new CLI from https://cli.heroku.com
=== painting-art Config Vars
DATABASE_URL:             [postgres]
LANG:                     en_US.UTF-8
RACK_ENV:                 production
RAILS_ENV:                production
RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT:      enabled
RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES: enabled
SECRET_KEY_BASE: [SECRET_KEY_BASE]
```

I am getting error like below

```
2018-05-29T07:21:12.395658+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2018-05-29T07:21:12.395584 #4]  INFO -- : [070ffe50-8753-4e61-8fe3-1273de66a29e] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 12ms (ActiveRecord: 3.4ms)
2018-05-29T07:21:12.396947+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2018-05-29T07:21:12.396874 #4] FATAL -- : [070ffe50-8753-4e61-8fe3-1273de66a29e]   
2018-05-29T07:21:12.397040+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2018-05-29T07:21:12.396976 #4] FATAL -- : [070ffe50-8753-4e61-8fe3-1273de66a29e] ActionView::Template::Error (Error connecting to Redis on 127.0.0.1:6379 (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)):
2018-05-29T07:21:12.397328+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2018-05-29T07:21:12.397247 #4] FATAL -- : [070ffe50-8753-4e61-8fe3-1273de66a29e]     18:       <tr>
```

help me to solve this error.
thank you

Comment: Please change the SECRET_KEY_BASE you have in your heroku config, now that you leaked it on the internet.

Comment: and change the password of your postgres db, because now everybody can use it and do bad things to it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to [provision a redis server on heroku](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/heroku-redis) first and then you can [configure and connect it](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-redis).

Comment: What if i don't want to use it

Comment: follow @Rohan's advice.

Comment: I dont want to use redis but heroku can't allow me app without redis ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are using redis service in your application and it is trying to connect to a local(127.0.0.1) machine on port(6379) which it is unable to.

Solution 1:

As mentioned in the post that you are basically performing simple crud and does not need redis service(assumption), then comment out the redis_url mentioned in the config or wherever it is mentioned.

Solution 2:

Add redis as an add-on heroku and use the URL provided by heroku in the application.
Another way would be using redis-service from redis labs(https://app.redislabs.com) and using this url in your application.

Comment: i have redis code in cable.yml development:
  adapter: async

test:
  adapter: async

production:
  adapter: async

  # adapter: redis
  # url: <%= ENV.fetch("REDIS_URL") { "redis://localhost:6379/1" } %>
  # channel_prefix: art-gallery_production
I removed it But still getting same error

Comment: I dont want to use redis but heroku can't allow me app without redis ?

Comment: comment out the whole cable.yml file and add it to git and try again

Comment: i deleted that file still it show me this redis error

Comment: I tried using the same approach and it worked for me..seems like wither redis url is currently being used in the app or the code being pushed is not correctly updated on heroku...are the logs same as shared above?